# Are dreidels supposed to be fair?

Tags: dreidel

In math terms, dice are expected to be "fair": every face should have the same odds of coming up on a proper roll. Before dice existed, people used pastern bones (which is knucklebone from livestock). Pasterns are not expected to be fair, and that's part of the game.

I'm very curious where dreidels lie on this spectrum of should or should not be fair.

This might not be the right stackexchange site for the question, but I don't know what would be better. I approach this question from the perspective of a dice collector who has a small number of dreidels. The dreidels are clearly "not fair", but I'm not sure if that is a defect, expected, or just tolerated.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. MY is indeed a site about judaism and this question very much risks being out of scope.

Comment: Maybe the collector has some dreidels that are relics from casinos or gamerooms managed by Mr Schultz or Mr Lansky.

Comment: I would guess that the odds of falling on any face should be one out of six so they should be *fair* but this is a question for a different stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weighted dice are unfair because someone may know which way they are weighted and take advantage.  No number on a die is better than any other all the time.  Which number you want depends on the game and on your position within the game.

Dreidels are different.  The game is completely one of chance (there is no real use of strategy and, while the order of the rolls you get matters a bit, each turn is basically the same (yes, the pot can be bigger or smaller and you can be more or less desperate to get a good roll, but...)).

The most important thing is that each side of the dreidel has the same meaning each time.  It's not like a die where getting a 6 in some cases is disastrous and other times 6 is the best and getting a 3 is the worst.  You either get the whole pot, half the pot, nothing, or you lose a coin.

So if the dreidel is weighted, it is weighted the same for everyone.  Knowing how it's weighted will make no difference.

So grab your coins (I'm partial to pennies but chocolate gelt is the modern tradition), all the children you can round up, and go play!

Comment: An unfair dreidel could be a game of skill instead of luck. Or could be unfair in some way that is not symmetrical. Consider: tends to land one way for clockwise and another for counterclockwise.

Comment: But on consideration of your answer, it seems like "it doesn't matter" is the expected state for "dreidel fairness".

Comment: Some of the most fun parts of playing dreidel are getting different kinds of spins.  Upside-down, for example.  A dreidel that lands more often on a particular side based on which way you spin it sounds awesome.  As long as everyone knows...

Comment: The standard dreidel game is unfairly weighted in favor of those who play earlier in the round. I'd *guess* that a dreidel weighted toward ג would exaggerate that effect and one weighted toward ש or פ would mitigate it.